# jQuery POST to GD image creation page

Tags: php, jquery, gd

I have a jquery form that posts to a callback page. The callback page uses PHP's GD library to create an image.

The PHP code looks like this:

```
<?php
include 'inc/config.php';

$caseNum = $_POST['caseNum'];
$wish = $_POST['wish'];
$selectedWishes = join(", ", $wish);
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$middlename = $_POST['middlei'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$address1 = $_POST['adr1'];
$address2 = $_POST['adr2'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$recipt = $_POST['recipt'];

$terms_accepted = $_POST['tou'];

if ($terms_accepted == 'accept') {

    mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_database);

    $select = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM children WHERE caseNumber="'.$caseNum.'" LIMIT 1 ');
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($select);

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    $im = imagecreatefrompng ("images/card_bg.png");
    $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $font = 'inc/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf';
    $size = 14;
    imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 130, 18, $color, $font, $caseNum);
    imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 52, 105, $color, $font, $row['age']);
    imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 108, 167, $color, $font, $row['name']);

    // Print wishes and word wrap
    $lines = explode('|', wordwrap($selectedWishes, 30, '|'));
    $y = 238;
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
    imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 18, $y, $color, $font, $line);
    $y += 23;
    }

    imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 339, 151, $color, $font, $fname.' '.$middlename.' '.$lname);
    imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 351, 175, $color, $font, $address1);
    imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 365, 196, $color, $font, $address2);
    imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 326, 218, $color, $font, $city);
    imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 474, 218, $color, $font, $zip);
    imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 340, 242, $color, $font, $phone);
    imagettftext($im, 9, 0, 333, 268, $color, $font, $email);

    if ($row['gender'] == 'male') {
        $check = imagecreatefrompng('images/checkmark.png');
        imagealphablending($check, true);
        imagesavealpha($check, false);
        imagecopymerge($im, $check, 74, 3, 0, 0, 10, 15, 80);
    }
    else if ($row['gender'] == 'female') {
        $check = imagecreatefrompng('images/checkmark.png');
        imagealphablending($check, true);
        imagesavealpha($check, false);
        imagecopymerge($im, $check, 74, 38, 0, 0, 10, 15, 80);
    }

    if ($recipt == 'yes') {
        $check = imagecreatefrompng('images/checkmark.png');
        imagealphablending($check, true);
        imagesavealpha($check, false);
        imagecopymerge($im, $check, 324, 383, 0, 0, 10, 15, 80);
    }
    else if ($recipt == 'no') {
        $check = imagecreatefrompng('images/checkmark.png');
        imagealphablending($check, true);
        imagesavealpha($check, false);
        imagecopymerge($im, $check, 367, 383, 0, 0, 10, 15, 80);
    }


    $imageName = rand();
    $ourFileName = $imageName.'.png'; 
    $ourFilePath = 'images/created_tags/';

    imagepng ( $im, $ourFilePath.$ourFileName );

    imagepng($im);
    imagepng($check);
    imagedestroy($check);
    imagedestroy($im); 

    readfile ( $ourFileName );

print $ourFilePath.$ourFileName;

    exit ();  

}


?>
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
$.post('selectChildCallback.php', $("#select_child_form").serialize(), function(data) {

                $("#post_image").append('<img src="'+ data.path +'" alt="card" />');

            }, 'json');
```

What I can't figure out is how to make the callback page not display the image, but just the path. Right now it prints the image data instead of an image path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
readfile ( $ourFileName );
```

This line is the problem.  According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), it echos the contents of a file to the screen.  So PHP is returning a image file (binary) with its file name concatenated to the end of the stream back to jQuery.

Remove this line, and this should work.

**EDIT**:

```
imagepng ( $im, $ourFilePath.$ourFileName );

imagepng($im);
imagepng($check);
```

Why do you call [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) 3 times?  If you don't give it a second parameter, it echos the image to the screen.  Also remove the last 2 `imagepng` lines.  PHP is actually returning 3 images concatenated together as well as the file name.

It should look like this:

```
$imageName = rand();
$ourFileName = $imageName.'.png'; 
$ourFilePath = 'images/created_tags/';

imagepng($im, $ourFilePath.$ourFileName);

imagedestroy($check);
imagedestroy($im); 

echo $ourFilePath.$ourFileName;

exit();
```